# Why my EF6 generated relationship not working?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables (`Jobs` and `Versions`) on a One to Many relationship in a PostgreSQL database. I have [generated a DB Context and Models](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/#using-an-existing-database-database-first) with dotnet-ef (EF6 Database-first) and created routes with [JsonApiDotNetCore](https://www.jsonapi.net/).

My two models :

```cs
// A Version (with one job)
[DisplayName("version")]
[Table("Versions")]
public partial class Version : Identifiable<long>
{

    [Attr(PublicName = "id-version")]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "id-job")]
    public long JobId { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "job")]
    public virtual Job JobIdNavigation { get; set; }
}

// A Job (with multiple Versions)
[DisplayName("job")]
[Table("Jobs")]
public partial class Job : Identifiable<long>
{
    public Job()
    {
        this.Versions = new HashSet<Version>();
    }

    [Attr(PublicName = "id-job")]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "versions")]
    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

And a DB Context :

```cs
public partial class TalendExplorerDbContext : DbContext
{

    [...]
    public virtual DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Version> Versions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("adminpack")
            .HasPostgresExtension("ltree")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "French_France.1252");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                .HasName("Jobs_pkey");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("job_id")
                .UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();

            [...]
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Version>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                .HasName("Versions_pkey");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("version_id")
                .UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();

            entity.Property(e => e.JobId).HasColumnName("job_id");

            [...]

            entity.HasOne<Job>(d => d.JobIdNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Versions)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.JobId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("Versions_id_job_fkey");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    [...]
}
```

With those, I can get a resource like a Job but there is no Versions linked:

```json
{
    "links": {
        "self": "https://localhost:5001/jobs/2"
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "jobs",
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "job2",
            "versions": []
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "https://localhost:5001/jobs/2"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this normal behavior ? How can I make my relationship work ?

### Edit 1

As suggest by [Michael Mairegger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637977/why-my-ef6-generated-relationship-not-working/68638113#68638113), I try to include the relationship on the request:

from `https://localhost:5001/jobs/2`

to `https://localhost:5001/jobs/2?include=versions`

but got an error:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "id": "4c6d79c9-0af7-419b-b89c-d3a61588b73a",
      "status": "400",
      "title": "The specified include is invalid.",
      "detail": "Relationship 'versions' does not exist on resource 'jobs'.",
      "source": { "parameter": "include" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Related entities are not loaded by default.  Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggest by a co-worker (and [Michael Mairegger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637977/why-my-ef6-generated-relationship-not-working/68638113?noredirect=1#comment121303355_68638113)), I had to specify [relationship with JsonApiDotNetCore](https://www.jsonapi.net/usage/resources/relationships.html).

So I need to change annotations on models:

```cs
// A Version (with one job)
[DisplayName("version")]
[Table("Versions")]
public partial class Version : Identifiable<long>
{

    [...]

    [HasOne(PublicName = "job")]
    public virtual Job JobIdNavigation { get; set; }
}

// A Job (with multiple Versions)
[DisplayName("job")]
[Table("Jobs")]
public partial class Job : Identifiable<long>
{

    [...]

    [HasMany(PublicName = "versions")]
    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the request `https://localhost:5001/jobs/2` show a version (relationship is working! hooray!):

```json
{
  "links": {
    "self": "https://localhost:5001/jobs/2"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "jobs",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
      "inserted-date": "2021-07-07T00:00:00+02:00",
      "modification-date": null,
      "path": "test",
      "purpose": "purpose",
      "description": "job de test",
      "name": "job1",
      "description-capture": null,
      "purpose-capture": null
    },
    "relationships": {
      "versions": {
        "links": {
          "self": "https://localhost:5001/jobs/2/relationships/versions",
          "related": "https://localhost:5001/jobs/2/versions"
        }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https://localhost:5001/jobs/2"
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to [Michael Mairegger anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638113/9197553) to get the content of related items via  `include` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with JsonApiDotNetCore but I think the reason is the same as in ODATA. The API does not load related data because you did not request it. Otherwise it can happen that you accidently load the whole database because every data is somehow connected to any other data.

The API supports an `include` query parameter where you can request the additional navigation properties. I think if you execute `https://localhost:5001/jobs/2?include=versions` the versions shall be in the results set.

See: [Including Relationships](https://www.jsonapi.net/usage/reading/including-relationships.html) for further information.

Comment: thanks for replying!

I had try to including relationships but got an error: `"Relationship 'versions' does not exist on resource 'jobs'."`

Comment: https://www.jsonapi.net/usage/resources/relationships.html try to specify [HasOne] and [HasMany] attribute on navigation properties. Maybe the API checks for that. Unfortunately I have never used this API. but because your question I will try it for my next project :)

Comment: I was writting this answer ^^ suggest by a co-worker !
Thx a lot Michael and have fun with JsonApiDotNetCore, a powerful tool for sure ;) !